# WebRequest getting response from an unintended page

Tags: xmlhttprequest

When I browse to
http://www.ivolatility.com/calc/?ticker=MSFT

... I intend to see their "Basic Calculator" screen for stock symbols (e.g. Microsoft: "MSFT").

However, before getting that, I get a license-agreement page requiring me to click an "I Agree" button before proceeding.

My goal is to write code that will download the HTML source of the Basic Calculator page. Unfortunately, when I execute the VBScript code below, I instead get the HTML of the license-agreement page.

Here I used VBScript, but I will settle for an answer in most any language.

Here is my code. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
Dim oHttp
Set oHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oHttp.open "GET", "http://www.ivolatility.com/calc/calc.j?ticker=MSFT", False
oHttp.send
WScript.Echo(oHttp.responseText)
```

Comment: Thanks Jay; you are right. My browser (Firefox) gave me the cookie name: CALCULATOR_DISCLAIMER_BASIC. Now the problem is I don't know what the command is to send the cookie.
Here is what I tried - it doesn't work:

oHttp.setRequestHeader "CALCULATOR_DISCLAIMER_BASIC", "accept"

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

There were two issues with my code. One: into CreateObject, I should have passed "MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp". The type that I passed originally, has a bug preventing it from (at least sometimes) sending cookies. And two, my syntax on setRequestHeader was incorrect. It should have been:
        oHttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", "CALCULATOR_DISCLAIMER_BASIC=agree"